# F# left join with multiple conditions, as a query expression

Tags: c#, linq, f#, entity-framework-6, left-join

In C# i can do a left join query, with multiple conditions. Like this C# example that runs fine:

```
using (var db = new CompanyContext())
{
    var q =
        from d in db.deps
        from e in db.emps.Where(e => d.id==e.dep_id && d.start_time<e.modified).DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
        select new { d, e };
    var result = q.ToList();
    // ...
}
```

I've tried to translate this to the following in F#:

```
use db = new CompanyContext()
let q = query {
    for d in db.deps do
    for e in db.emps.Where(fun e -> d.id=e.dep_id && d.start_time<e.modified).DefaultIfEmpty() do // left join
    select ( d, e )}
let result = q.ToList()
// ...
```

But the F# version results in an Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable '_arg1' of type
> 'MyLib.dep' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

What is wrong with my F# query?

**EDIT**: using an anonymous record `select {| d = d; e = e |}` instead of `select ( d, e )` as suggested, results in the same Exception

**EDIT**:
Full Exception (There is no inner exception. It's null):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: variable '_arg1' of type 'MyLib.dep' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitNewArray(NewArrayExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetLambdaExpression(Expression argument)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetLambdaExpression(MethodCallExpression callExpression, Int32 argumentOrdinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultIfEmptyTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectManyTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ConsoleApplication1.main(String[] argv) in C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.fs:line 780
```

`groupJoin` doesn't seem to compile with my extra condition. Visual Studio complains that it doesn't know `d`, and underlines it in `d.start_time<e.modified`:

```
use db = new CompanyContext()
let q = query {
    for d in db.deps do
    groupJoin e in db.emps.Where(fun e -> d.start_time<e.modified) on (d.id=e.dep_id) into es // left join
    for e in es.DefaultIfEmpty() do
    select ( d, e )}
let result = q.ToList()
```

> FS0039    The value, namespace, type or module 'd' is not defined.

Comment: The problem may be due to the fact that you are selecting an f# tuple, and there are reported problems with that, see [Query builder with EF core can't return fsharp tuples (and sometimes new objects) using async methods #3782](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3782) and [Tuples in query expression with grouping cannot be translated to SQL #47](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/47).

Comment: Try using an [anonymous record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records) instead: `select {| d = d; e = e |}`.

Comment: There might also be something going wrong with your use of `DefaultIfEmpty()` to perform a left outer join, see [leftOuterJoin is different from C# version, workaround doesn't work for double left join #6552](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/6552).

Comment: @dbc i didn't know that about anonymous records also exist in F# (thanks!). however the result is the same. i'm looking at your second link about `DefaultIfEmpty()`. it looks very similar, but the examples there are not using multiple conditions. i haven't figured out yet, whether i can use anything there for my problem

Comment: Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  The traceback may provide a hint as to where things are going wrong.

Comment: @dbc i added the information

Comment: @Abel thanks for pointing that out. i tried a `groupJoin` (added it as example). there seems to be some scoping issue with it, so i couldn't get it to compile. maybe there is a trick i don't know about, to use arbitrary boolean expressions

Answer (score 1):

I think i've found a solution. This seems to produce the expected result, with `groupJoin`:

```
use db = new CompanyContext()
let q = query {
    for d in db.deps do
    groupJoin e in db.emps on (d.id=e.dep_id) into es
    for e in es.Where(fun e -> d.start_time<e.modified).DefaultIfEmpty() do
    select ( d , e )}
let result = q.ToList()
```

You don't have to use the `on` clause, by using a dummy condition that's always true, like `0=0`:

```
use db = new CompanyContext()
let q = query {
    for d in db.deps do
    groupJoin e in db.emps on (0=0) into es
    for e in es.Where(fun e -> d.id=e.dep_id && d.start_time<e.modified).DefaultIfEmpty() do
    select ( d , e )}
let result = q.ToList()
```

The examples also work with `leftOuterJoin` instead of `groupJoin`.

Opinion:

I don't like how `leftOuterJoin` implicitly applies `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to what is declared by the `into` part (`into es` in the above examples). Because then if you want to add more conditions in a following `for` clause like me with `.Where`, then you still need to apply `.DefaultIfEmpty()` so that there is at least 1 result again anyway, because `for` is a next and separate operation. Might as well use groupJoin that always needs `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to do a left join